# Where can I find the Fabric setUserIdentifier key value?

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric

Please show me where to find the setUserIdentifier key is available on Fabric Crashlytics?

```
Crashlytics.sharedInstance().setUserEmail("user@mail.com")
Crashlytics.sharedInstance().setUserIdentifier("12345")
Crashlytics.sharedInstance().setUserName("Test User")


Crashlytics.sharedInstance().setUserIdentifier("??????????"). where to find the key here?
```

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Do you mean where in the Fabric website it's located?

Comment: Yes!  Where do I find it in fabric website.

Answer (score 3):

This is arbitrary identifier is created by your application. Usually generated from email by some hashing function (MD5, SHA-1. etc). Basically, this id could be used to reference particular user instead of exposing it's email, name, last name, etc in Crashlytics logs, UI and reports.

Here's the doc:

```
/**
 *  Specify a user identifier which will be visible in the Crashlytics UI.
 *
 *  Many of our customers have requested the ability to tie crashes to specific end-users of their
 *  application in order to facilitate responses to support requests or permit the ability to reach
 *  out for more information. We allow you to specify up to three separate values for display within
 *  the Crashlytics UI - but please be mindful of your end-user's privacy.
 *
 *  We recommend specifying a user identifier - an arbitrary string that ties an end-user to a record
 *  in your system. This could be a database id, hash, or other value that is meaningless to a
 *  third-party observer but can be indexed and queried by you.
 *
 *  Optionally, you may also specify the end-user's name or username, as well as email address if you
 *  do not have a system that works well with obscured identifiers.
 *
 *  Pursuant to our EULA, this data is transferred securely throughout our system and we will not
 *  disseminate end-user data unless required to by law. That said, if you choose to provide end-user
 *  contact information, we strongly recommend that you disclose this in your application's privacy
 *  policy. Data privacy is of our utmost concern.
 *
 *  @param identifier An arbitrary user identifier string which ties an end-user to a record in your system.
 */
- (void)setUserIdentifier:(nullable NSString *)identifier;
```

Answer (score 1):

Mike from Fabric here. To find this within your Fabric dashboard, use the following steps:

1. From the Crashlytics dashboard, click on the specific issue.
2. From the specific issue, click on "View all sessions".
3. From there, you'll see the user identifier if logged under "Device Statistics" on the far right of the page.

Comment: And how to see it when using Firebase Crashlytics? Username was set according to https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports#set_user_ids
I would imagine it being visible under specific issue  -> Key tab, but it isn't.

Comment: Mike in Firebase setUserIdentifier doesn't seem to work on the release build is this by design?

Comment: This should work within Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports#set_user_identifiers  - Crashlytics.sharedInstance().setUserIdentifier("123456789") or Crashlytics.setUserIdentifier("user123456789"); depending on iOS or Android respectively. If it's not working, I'd recommend reaching out to support to diagnose.